# Find a non-trivial outer automorphism of $A_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

> The symmetric group $S_n$ can be decomposed as a semi-direct product
>   of the alternating group $A_n$ and a subgroup of $S_n$ of order 2. Use
>   this fact to find a non-trivial outer automorphism of $A_n$ for $n \ge
>  3$.

Taking $S_n \cong A_n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$ it would seem obvious that Out$(A_n)= \mathbb{Z}_2$. I'm not sure how to find the actual outer automorphism, however.

Using the above hypothesis, what is a non-trivial outer automorphism of $A_n$ for $n \ge 3$?

Comment: Conjugate by a transposition?

Comment: Why would it seem obvious that $Our(A_n)=\mathbb Z_n$ from the fact that $S_n$ is that direct product?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n\ge 3$ and $n\neq 6$ the non-trivial outer automorphism of $A_n$ is conjugation by an odd permutation, and we have $Out(A_n)\simeq C_2$. For $n=6$ we have $Out(A_6)\simeq C_2\times C_2$.

Edit: The question, why this outer automorphism of $A_n$ is not inner, has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543691/why-is-conjugation-by-an-odd-permutation-in-s-n-not-an-inner-automorphism-on).

Comment: I'm sorry but can you please elaborate on why these automorphisms are non-trivial in $Out(A_n)$?

Comment: This has been elaborated at [this MSE-question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543691/why-is-conjugation-by-an-odd-permutation-in-s-n-not-an-inner-automorphism-on).

Comment: I read through that question and answer but still can't quite figure out why conjugation by an odd permutation is non-trivial in $C_2$ and $C_2 \times C_2$?

Comment: Because it is not inner, i.e., not of the form $\phi(x)=gxg^{-1}$ for some $g\in A_n$. This is proved there.

Comment: Sorry, but what is $C_n$?

Comment: @algebra.And.analysis $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$, i.e., $C_n=\{1,g,g^2,\ldots ,g^{n-1}\}$. For an example see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicGroupC4.html).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you. This is my first time to see this symbol.