Automorphism group of $A_n$, $n \geq 7$
I am trying to find the automorphism group of the alternating groups $A_n$. However, when it comes to $A_7$, I have found it difficult to prove that $\operatorname {Aut}(A_7) \cong S_7$. (I have checked the conclusion with GAP, and $\operatorname {Aut}(A_8) \cong S_8$ is also true.)
What we have are:

$\operatorname {Aut}(A_3)\cong(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \\ 
   \operatorname {Aut}(A_4)\cong S_4 \\
   \operatorname {Aut}(A_5)\cong S_5 \\
   \operatorname {Aut}(A_6)\cong S_6 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$

So can we prove that for all $n \geq 7$, $\operatorname {Aut}(A_n)\cong S_n$?

according to the wiki article here, your statement re. aut An is true for n>=7. https://static.hlt.bme.hu/semantics/external/pages/Schur-lemma/en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group.html

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709214/find-a-non-trivial-outer-automorphism-of-a-n might be relevant.

See wikipedia, and the references given there: "the natural maps
${\displaystyle \mathrm {S} _{n}\to \operatorname {Aut} (\mathrm {S} _{n})\to \operatorname {Aut} (\mathrm {A} _{n})}$ are isomorphisms, for $n>6$." The main part is proved, for example, in this duplicate.

@DietrichBurde I might be stupid, but is it obvious that the map $\operatorname{Aut} S_n \rightarrow \operatorname {Aut} A_n$ is surjective? Is it easy to prove that every automorphism of $A_n$ can be extended to an automorphism of $S_n$? (I'm struggling with this problem)
